# Rest API V1 configurable-products Options Value

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I am post Data

```
{
  "option": {
    "id": 39,
    "attribute_id": "134",
    "label": "Beden",
 "values": [
            {
                "value_index": 18
            },
            {
                "value_index": 17
            }
        ],
     "product_id": 47
  }
```

But not add "value_index": 17. I didnt understand Get result This

```
[
    {
        "id": 26,
        "attribute_id": "134",
        "label": "Beden",
        "position": 0,
        "values": [],
        "product_id": 47
    }
]
```

Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

What's version do you use?

If in **Magento2**, `value_index` is required, you could post json like below.

Change the `attribute_set_id` to your `attribute_set_id`.

Change the `value_index` to your `configurable attribute option value`.

Change the `configurable_product_links` to your child product id.

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "MS-Champ",
    "name": "Champ Tee",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "configurable",
    "extension_attributes": {
          "configurable_product_options":[
            {
              "attribute__id":"136",
              "label":"Size",
              "values":[
                {
                  "value_index":340
                },
                {
                  "value_index":341
                }
              ]
            }
          ],
         "configurable_product_links":[
           21,
           22
         ]
    }
  }
}
```